# Word for someone who wants everything living to die

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

I'm looking for a word to refer to a person who is in favor of all living beings not surviving.

A compound word is acceptable.

Comment: Do you want a word to describe the person or their belief?

Comment: People, plants, animals, undiscovered aliens? On Earth and/or elsewhere?

Comment: [*Freud's Eros and **Thanatos** theory says that all instincts fit into two classes: the life drive (Eros) and the **death drive...***](https://www.verywellmind.com/life-and-death-instincts-2795847)

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for the word **omnicidal.** This is derived from *omnicide,* [defined by MW as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omnicide)

> the destruction of all life or all human life (as by nuclear war)

Comment: ... and both 'suicidal' and 'homicidal' are primarily used to show a personal disposition rather than 'pertaining to suicide ...'.